# Improve script for searching palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

## How can I make it better/more efficiently/elegant?

The script works without issues,  but maybe there is a way to improve it?

```
def isPalindrome(q):
   first = 0
   second  = len(q)-1
   for symbols in q:
       while first != len(q)-1:
           if q[first] != q[second]:
               return False
           else:
               first += 1
               second -=1
       if first == len(q)-1:
           return True
```

Comment: What is the point of `for symbols in q`?

Comment: Improving working code is off-topic, but consider "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama".  That's a palindrome.  What's your required inputs and outputs?  Consider stripping spaces/punctuation and normalizing case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> q = "abba"
>>> q == q[::-1]
True
```

You can also use recursion:

```
def isPalindrome(text):
    if text:
        return text[0] == text[-1] and isPalindrome(text[1:-1])
    else:
        return True
```

You can always use `timeit` to measure efficiency:

```
>>> setup = """
... def isPalindrome(text):
...         if text:
...             return text[0] == text[-1] and isPalindrome(text[1:-1])
...         else:
...             return True
...
...
... def isPalindrome2(text):
...     return text == text[::-1]
...
... """
>>> timeit.timeit('isPalindrome("amanaplanacanalpanama")', setup=setup)
4.524680453999963
>>> timeit.timeit('isPalindrome2("amanaplanacanalpanama")', setup=setup)
0.33293550200005484
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome :)